# Is cloning faster than filling, Java?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm working on a console ascii renderer, it's my first project, currently it's a 2D only renderer.

The slowest part, which I would like to optimize is filling the matrix of chars which I use as a Canvas.

I'm using the usual setup:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
 for(int c=0;c<array[0].length;c++)
   array[i][c]=' ';
```

It's pretty slow, especially fir higher resolutions.

Are there any faster way? Because I saw another question that suggest that the fill(c,x) function in the Array library does the same thing.

Maybe cloning a prefilled array is faster?

Any suggestions?

TLDR:
I used two innested for loops, and I read another thread about the fill(c,x) function on this site which suggests the code does the same thing. Anything faster?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how high is the resolution for *this* to be the bottleneck?

Comment: The best way to know which method is faster is by benchmarking, just try it out

Comment: Pietro, this is an extraordinary claim, that this is the bottleneck. You should expand the question: How big are the row and column sizes likely to be? How have you determined that this is the bottleneck?

Comment: I solved the problem, the problem wasn't the char matrix, it was the fact that once the matrix was filled I was converting the matrix to a String without using the StringBuilder, so the bottleneck wasn't actually there. Thank you anyway!